# Array losing records on post with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I have an array in jQuery resulting from a csv. It is created by:

```
var csvrows = e.target.result.split("\n");
```

It looks like this:

```
"1,Fred,Dryer,FredDryer1@email.com,Backfield,North\r","2,Franco,Harris,FrancoHarris2@email.com,Corp,South\r","3,Jim,Brown,JimBrown3@email.com,Field,South\r","4,Fred,Dryer,FredDryer4@email.com,Backfield,North\r",etc.
```

The csv has 1200 rows in it. I verify it's length in the console with:

```
console.log('records: ' + csvrows.length)
```

*records: 1200*

I post it by ajax for processing and database insertion.

```
$csvdata = $_POST['csvdata'];
```

The problem is this. print_r($csvdata) stops at row 992.

I'm losing data on post. No clue why. MySQL packet size? Is there some kind of string length with the array in ajax? I explode and trim CSVdata in php to add keys and remove the \r. maybe if I did that in jQuery before post?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What is your max post size?
Did you check whats arriving (debug in php script)?

Thats the setting for post size(php.ini):

```
post_max_size=8M
```

Comment: I will check to see if I have access to it. I'm using GoDaddy hosting. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: However, the spreadsheet is only 68KB. And, the console.log of *nearly* all the results says it's about 250kb...